# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMediatR' and no accessible extension method 'AddMediatR' accepting

Tags: .net

I'm using .NET 6 in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

> I get: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddMediatR' and no accessible extension method 'AddMediatR' accepting
> a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why?

Comment: I dont think AddMediatR is part of IServiceCollection by default, you're probably missing a nuget package. Possibly this one: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you must

```
Install-Package MediatR
```

then for access in `IServiceCollection` must

```
Install-Package MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

Comment: MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package is deprecated. We can use MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjectionFixed as suggested by @DivyaPrakash

Answer (score 3):

First you must

```
Install-Package MediatR
```

then for access in `IServiceCollection` must

```
Install-Package MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjectionFixed
```

as `Package MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` is now deprecated.

Edit *I had to see & they really did call it Fixed*:

[image]